# Laravel 5: Replace string in query results (Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Is it possible to return all columns from a table, but if a string (value) contains a specific word, remove that word?

For example, I have a table like this:

```
 -------------------------------------------------
| id | article_desc     | article_link   | active |
|----|------------------|----------------|--------|
| 1  | Hello, world!    | http://test.co |    0   |
| 2  | ReplaceWord Test | http://null.org|    1   |
 -------------------------------------------------
```

"**ReplaceWord**" should be replaced to "" (nothing). So article_desc of ID 2 should return "**Test**".

Is there any way to do this in Laravel (Eloquent) without using a foreach or something? Is there any built-in function?

This is my controller where I am getting this data.

`return Article::where('active', 1)->orderBy('create_date', 'desc')->get();`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this word to be replaced permanently (in database) or only when working with the `Article` model?

Comment: Only when working with the Article model, I don't want it to be replaced in DB either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eloquent queries return a Laravel collection, so you can use the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) function to loop over the results and replace the strings.

```
return Article::where('active', 1)
    ->orderBy('create_date', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($article) {
        $article->article_desc = str_replace('ReplaceWord', '', $article->article_desc);

        return $article;
    });
```

If you want the value to be replaced for every query, you can create [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this field on your `Article` model.

```
public function getArticleDescAttribute($value)
{
    return str_replace('ReplaceWord', '', $value)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the comment. This returns:

`[
null,
null,
null,
null
]`

For the accessor, seems interesting, but I only need it for this query :-(

Comment: @KennyHietbrink `return $article;` was missing from the closure passed to the `map()` method . This should fix the `null` issue you were having.